# Nested IFs Excel - Alternative

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have a large data set with multiple columns - each row has a case type and a contract value. On another sheet I have a mapping table (shown below) of case types and value ranges that decide what "Type" each row should be assigned too.

For example a row with case type 1 and a contract value of $20,000,000 would be type 1 - a row with Case type 3 with a value of $4,000,000 would be Type 3 as it falls between the value ranges for type 3 (N4 and O4)

I know I could hardcode an IF statement in 14 helper columns to fulfill for each Case Type and then combine cells that aren't blank but I'd love to know is there a smarter way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Use index with two matches; one with 0 as the range_lookup and one with -1 as the range_lookup.

Comment: Quinn, did you ever get a useable answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the header of the mapping table data set needs to be adjusted. Unmerge those cells that are merged and then give each column a title. Doing so should result in something similar to this:

[image: example of header]

I then created a results table on a second worksheet that looks like this:

[image: results table]

It may be grossly over-simplified, but hopefully you can modify the formula as needed.

Now here's the formula I created in `C2`:

`{=INDEX(MappingTable!$K$1:$S$1,1,SUMPRODUCT(IF(B2<INDIRECT("MappingTable!"&ADDRESS(MATCH($A2,MappingTable!$I$2:$I$15,0)+1,11)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH($A2,MappingTable!$I$2:$I$15,0)+1,19)),1,0))+1)}`

*Note: This is an array formula and must be committed with* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>*. The curly braces - { } - that surround the formula above will not be entered by the user, but will be created once the formula is committed as described above.*

**KEY NOTES:**

`B2` will reference the `Contract Value` in your results table.

`"MappingTable!"` is a hardcoded value that should be the name of your sheet plus the exclamation point at the end.

`$A2` will reference the `Case Type` in your results table.

`MappingTable!$I$2:$I$15` is an absolute reference to the *row* headers on the mapping table.

`11`, which is found in the first `ADDRESS` function, is a reference to Column K on the mapping table worksheet. It can also be written as `COLUMN(K:K)`.

`19`, which is found in the second`ADDRESS` function, is a reference to Column S on the mapping table worksheet. It can also be written as `COLUMN(S:S)`.